# Autofac module registrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-module

I have mostly used Ninject, so I apologize if I mix up terminology.

I created a logger module to handle NLog using the destination class name as the logger name.  It is very similar to this: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html?highlight=log4net

I also have a module created in my service layer that takes care of all of the service level registrations.  Looks like this:

```
public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.Register(x => new AccountService(x.Resolve<ILogger>()))
            .As<IAccountService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

Here is my autofac registration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterModule(new LoggingModule());
builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
app.UseAutofacMvc();
```

At runtime, I get an exception saying ILogger has not been registered, am I missing something about how the modules work that is causing ILogger to not be visible in my service module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module can do many things : it can register new components and/or subscribe to *Autofac* events.

In this case, the `LoggingModule` doesn't register `ILog`. It intercepts the preparation of other components using the `Preparing` event and add a new `Parameter` that will create the `ILog` if needed.

You won't be able to resolve `ILog` but if your `AccountService` implementation requires a `ILog` the following `Parameter` will be triggered and will provide the `ILog` implementation.

```
new ResolvedParameter(
    (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog),
    (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)
)
```

All you have to do is to register your type without trying to explicitly create the instance :

```
builder.RegisterType<AccountService>()
       .As<IAccountService>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense since I tried changing my registration to Type registration and it was working.  How would I go about getting the module to work with resolve statements, any documentation you can point me too on that subject?

Comment: Have a look at `IRegistrationSource` : http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html